# Scoping the has_many through data points for each model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, has-many-through

I have a has_many through association with four models

```
class Integration < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :integration_profiles
 has_many :profiles, through: :integration_profiles

 # has `provider` column
end

class IntegrationProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :integration
 belongs_to :profile

# has a `data` column
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :integration_profiles
 has_many :integrations, through: :integration_profiles
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :integrations
 has_many :profiles, through: :integrations
end
```

Every time a integration creates a profile, I call:

```
p = Profile.find_or_create_by(email: "email")
```

Given I only have 1 user in my database and all integrations & profiles should belong to the user, the user has more than one integration with repeating profiles and therefore has more integration_profiles than there is profiles

```
u = User.first
Profile.all.count => 977
u.profiles.count => 1042
IntegrationProfile.all.count => 1042
```

What I'd like to do is return all of the profiles **related** to that user (so only 977) with each profile's integration providers that belong to that user. In other words, I'd like to have a profile outputted and all of the providers (or integrations if you will) that it's associated with.

The goal is to essentially do a loop as such:

```
profiles.each do |profile|
   profile.providers.each do |provider|
      puts provider
   end
end
```

I tried grouping and failed badly.

This is where I am stuck:

```
 u.profiles.select("*, integration_profiles.data as integration_profiles_data, integrations.provider as i_p, profiles.*")
 => returns 1042 profiles with each's i_p as provider
 u.profiles.select("profiles.*, integrations.provider as ipdata").group("profiles.id, ipdata")
 => I cannot even do a count, it fails...
```

**UPDATE:**

Got it semi working like this:

```
<% profile.integrations.where(user_id: current_user.id).distinct.each do |int| %>
    <%= int.provider %>
<% end%>
```

With this in my controller:

```
u.profiles.where(found: true).select("*, integration_profiles.data as integration_profiles_data, profiles.*").includes(integrations: :user)
```

This was horrible because it resulted to 96 sql queries for 20 profiles. Any ideas how to make all this into one query?